# How do you find out the DayOfTheWeek given a datetime in MySql?

Tags: sql, mysql, algorithm

Given a datetime column in mysql 5, I want to find out the day of the week ?

But the function DAYOFWEEK returns 1 for Sunday.

I want 1 to denote monday, 2 tuesday etc.. and 7 to denote Sunday.

Is there a one-liner (that can be embedded in a larger SQL statement) that implements this function ?

```
f(x) => y

such that:
   f(1) = 7
   f(n) = n-1 for n in range [2,7]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **purely arithmetic formula** is

```
SELECT ((DAYOFWEEK(myDate) + 5) % 7) + 1 AS MondayBasedDOW
```

Although in SQL we often solve this with a **CASE statement** (cf astender's answer)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(myDate) = 1 THEN 7 ELSE DAYOFWEEK(myDate) -1 END
       AS MondayBasedDOW
```

Now... MySQL also provides the function ***WEEKDAY()*** which is similar to ***DAYOFWEEK()***, but is

- Monday-based
- Zero-based

i.e. Monday = 0, Tuesday = 1 ... Sunday = 6
So you can simply use

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(myDate) + 1 AS MondayBasedDOW
```

but of course that's a lot less fun than using modulo arithmetic ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try 
CASE WHEN n = 1 THEN 7 ELSE n -1 END